# What is preventing the skill[id].Value increment? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

If I create a button with the name "Level 0" and onmousedown I have it run learnSkill(3) it only increments the skill[3].Value to 1, then it picks up a click but does nothing, why?

I am trying to code a skill tree, I haven't gotten very far because of issues like this so it's mostly empty.

```
    var skill = new Array();

    function Skill(value, name, type, tier, column, info, requirement) {
        this.Value = value;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Type = type;
        this.Tier = tier;
        this.Column = column;
        this.Info = info;
        this.Req = requirement;
        //skill[id].Req
    }

    function SkillReq(id, amount, reqby) {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Amount = amount;
        this.By = reqby;
        //skill[id].Req.Id
        //skill[id].Req.Amount
        //skill[id].Req.By
    }

    skill[1] = new Skill(0, "Unholy Sphere", "Tree 2", 0, 1, new Array(), new SkillReq(0, 0, 3));
    skill[3] = new Skill(0, "Dark Circle", "Tree 2", 1, 0, new Array(), new SkillReq(1, 3, 0));

    function canLearn(id) {
        alert("in canlearn");
        canLearn = true;
        return canLearn;
    }

    function canUnlearn(id) {

    }

    function learnSkill(id) {
        alert("id: "+id);
        if (!canLearn(id)) {
            alert("cannot learn");
            return;
        }
        // Increase current skill value
        skill[id].Value++;
        alert(skill[id].Value);
        // totalSP--; Decrease totalSP, must declare first
        // Update button to show new level of skill value
        document.getElementById(id).value = "Level "+skill[id].Value;
    }

    function unlearnSkill(id) {
        if (!canUnlearn(id)) {
            return;
        }
    }

    function onClickTalent(id) {

    }

    function rmbDown(e)
    {
        var isRMB = false;
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.which)
            isRMB = (e.which == 3);
        else if (e.button)
            isRMB = (e.button == 2);
        return isRMB;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your `canLearn` function inside of it, the `canLearn` identifier you assign to true is the function itself, to create a new variable in the function scope use the var keyword

```
function canLearn(id) {
    alert("in canlearn");
    var canLearn = true;
    return canLearn;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've been looking at the code so much I didn't even notice var wasn't there xP

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what it is you're trying to do, but here's one problem:

```
function canLearn(id) {
    alert("in canlearn");
    canLearn = true;
    return canLearn;
}
```

That function will "self-descruct" the first time it's called, because you're setting the global symbol "canLearn" to `true`. Trouble is, "canLearn" is already used - as the name of that function!  Thus, subsequent attempts to call "canLearn" will fail because its value is no longer a function object.